# Color encoding in multi layer chart not relfecting as intended in Vega-Lite

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I am attempting to encode specific colours to circle marks plotted on a second Y-Axis. However, it seems as if the color encoding is inherited from an encoding declared in a preceding layer.

This is the intended outcome:
[image]

However, my [specification](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Y+Q5H48n+sNxtn4eiS4zK+cxdKzc9qe9Geiu57foJ0ZWw9sAD5bFBXleQAflsGU5TUAAKD9e1tGlfyZBRNUodYIE1ABKWxUDgr9qT1c0RyvdA1SYOBBFBJ9Wxfdt3zUPd8IDGM-0A4CQPAyDkEwWCGM-BCDhaYcULQjDsNwvj4KjRChOIqsIzIii3HdZD5wYTA2AgGgAC8NVAEscEzKU6GyKA5HUcwIxwJBlGUcwyGbZM5GMhzNBATJGzdNzZRoY1oiYNhsDYeUlEUwQTHMgBlHSNWhJzdAQWRrRRNVizYdS0FAAKgvlNzbhgWVogQQVlEyd1zgq0KkGLOBXFQYx3Oq2qFRACxPnQXM4HzQs6FLR8lGQZwAGtMpAAzMyYR4lAADwAeSlKUIDrNA+RALTdJBVaNLYQRFhwNBxT0VkkjMuzZFc0BptG4yKK8kAzAsKwbEEBwnFcMVi0M6JZTOnRLWmmhrVAMKAEFzrK1APFZGRnCGVBZFVQRWWLa7fMEO7GiBfqxs+zMAEcGEsRZ1EWUhsmJiGQE67qi1LIJZAzJLetsaChoAdRgWwCFsDTaWkpZMMcszBEKtybvR69l1XbHxuiWRgpuQRsmgHQ9JUYKkHMIwQG+VJ0kyCAp2DUNsl134DZKA0jQZk2lFiWQEiSPW-kNoMZzNbJ7cdn59f0S3zxtj3VIlc6NUMEAAGJ1nWcougAIWKbII5xEHvHWOOk7EEHikqEwQaT9ZigAEVj9YQBZUL4y8-S6Ep8qlB+5qxbRrzw5vchpbKVTG7q8OrSgV17PLiqkzazNqfFHqSzhbJBpGtzZfQSb3pAOaFqWuH+G8Vb1o1bexTYHa9oO5wjqUE7ZiHtyrub27oge25nteqaca+9AfsV-7AdG0HwY1KGlAwzhgjQQSMlAo1vhLdAmNmhlA+m-EABMiZ0DUDQMmVYAbWhAWA+KotQDizuu3O8a44Gv0zPLYqFglaAJTGrZQGstb1R1k7c2fs3Yhg9koM2vtDZnmtiaThMQ4jcJdkbd2pCvYiItnwi8QclAh0KNrKOMd46JyUMncoqd06Z2zrnfO6jC4ly6GXCu7kq6jQppmeuIAe6ozvkwohq4jjd2cMoJufdoCD3OsPSqoAx41hBvEAA4tmXos8XDz30rjfyL816LWWqgfea0YqbSUMLUWkcTAmGKMUXk5ND67RoPtVAh04DHSsJfbx187FQPujcJ69w3rk2ie-Vxn8MHfzcr-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-UBqDS2KFqJAkhN6DGtF4ThpJszGuy0hKM1ZvJbmultL81FpyqWm+6x2XVu5by-llSm033wXuttYrn6SuxR-WVfbYbmpXeA61qqJnbs1d6vdhzmlupPQur1SAzUDpw5a9d85N0EeiDurV9jUQLPJVK+dRqvU+rhiAf1gaR7B30DtMmbkVYQ1ABAtaMAXBwETJs0asnzBuMMgmPyI8WypXccDJqvc-EhptPze0pDE0L2xdYZwUAypatAYpk+egD5HyKU5sp9aBVVKFZAu6SGn4SrI5mdDvb+lYdozgodxH2MCTM0F6IPHPUmqk2rXSMw0BSh0EtVdjzoixeWNBXmgsq1QQE0oVkuyla+by6Z5YDoGyumVrQs5lhFFMIjl0TrXXblmPuQvXL6Ag3BvapGb8MlzOYsswg6ztmTWVccyU0+cAXOFOKaUmDjbRrwei7U-zjSX5SpC9QsLgy6NRcdaNgigZSEpdGmltgGWssebIQlijvGTXUc6dgkrl70Dlfs1VhDMXatwjjPck50nM2tYuUaN0piPKNf65gOuzzb3Gcu8xeFiL1DPrja+yJL30CfqUGWlaJOIEVtWhyzAXKNS8qrQzNm7IyWbSp+ZaIkUO5FByEEUyO0MkRxAiBRyF9NvVOq620VAXO2E+lb9Y7QDsORZbRjn8rrlnIPe0105bl7uPbjc9z7y7BA-d9X9xyn6JeNVjVRbTRmRv5dB9j5FjpUV44xW+qbH7cXktJ5DcnaBKcM5pzW+n3rzJM45FyVAng2cMw51z2wPO+ci2+YLoXNyNuCubVbvbHaDtoZ7Qr-tircNW8dzOtazXde1Qe6gTLBvV36re0lpdSvTdlYtz7lXYVlIifkWJwQEnh00Zk9ENTcANNuPj9DavoAIDijYENTME+p9aYqqJmQQ+1a3bcqpzTa-4+AMX8v8fB-XTr-OCyIAA) is returning this output (yellow being applied to both circle marks):

[image]

Here is a snippet of the encoding:

```
            {
          "name": "Production PY",
          "mark": {
            "type": "circle", "filled": true,
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Year",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "sort": null
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Production PY",
              "scale": {"zero": false},
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null,
              "format": ","
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Production PY Legend",
              "scale": {
                "range": ["red"]
              },
              "legend": {
                "title": ""
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

What changes to the spec can I apply to achieve the intended outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? If so, set resolve -> fill to independent.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Financial Year": 2023,
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "Usage CY": 98.522,
        "Usage PY": 88.556,
        "Target": 82.756,
        "Production CY": 57477,
        "Production PY": 52805
      },
      {
        "Financial Year": 2023,
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "Usage CY": 31.618,
        "Usage PY": 38.942,
        "Target": 36.392,
        "Production CY": 57477,
        "Production PY": 52805
      }
    ]
  },
  "height": 400,
  "width": 500,
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "'Production Current FY'", "as": "Production CY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Production Prior FY'", "as": "Production PY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Electricity Target'", "as": "Target Legend"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' Prior FY'", "as": "CategoryPY"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' Current FY'", "as": "CategoryCY"},
    {
      "calculate": "datum['Production CY'] > 10000? format(datum['Production CY'],'.4s') :datum['Production CY'] ",
      "as": "label1"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['Production PY'] > 10000? format(datum['Production PY'],'.4s') :datum['Production PY'] ",
      "as": "label2"
    }
  ],
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "contains": "padding"},
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "labelFontSize": 8,
      "columns": 2,
      "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Electricity CY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": 0, "size": 30, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Year",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0},
              "sort": null
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Electricity Intensity (kWh / ton Production)"
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryCY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Renewables Current FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Current FY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#39A34B", "#5AC8FA", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryCY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": -30, "size": 30, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Year",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0},
              "sort": null
            },
            "y": {"field": "Usage PY", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryPY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Renewables Current FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Current FY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#39A34B", "#5AC8FA", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryPY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET",
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "xOffset": 30,
            "size": 30,
            "color": "#FFCC00",
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Year",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0},
              "sort": null
            },
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Target Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["#FFCC00"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [{"filter": "datum['Usage CY'] != null"}],
          "name": "Electricity CY Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 13,
            "fontSize": 12
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Year", "type": "ordinal", "sort": null},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".1f"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": -18,
            "fontSize": 12
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Year", "type": "ordinal", "sort": null},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".1f"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 43,
            "fontSize": 12
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Year", "type": "ordinal", "sort": null},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".1f"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"}, "axis": {"y": "independent"}}
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "layer": [
            {
              "name": "Production CY",
              "mark": {"type": "circle", "filled": true, "tooltip": true},
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Production CY",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "title": "Production (ton)",
                  "format": ","
                },
                "fill": {
                  "field": "Production CY Legend",
                  "scale": {"range": ["#666666"]},
                  "legend": {"title": ""}
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Production PY",
              "mark": {"type": "circle", "filled": true, "tooltip": true},
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Production PY",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": null,
                  "format": ","
                },
                "fill": {
                  "field": "Production PY Legend",
                  "scale": {"range": ["red"]},
                  "legend": {"title": ""}
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Production CY Data Labels",
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "dx": 0,
                "dy": -10,
                "fontSize": 12,
                "fontWeight": 300,
                "font": "Segoe UI",
                "color": "#000000"
              },
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Production CY",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "axis": null,
                  "format": ","
                },
                "text": {"field": "label1"}
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Production PY Data Labels",
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "dx": 0,
                "dy": -10,
                "fontSize": 12,
                "fontWeight": 200,
                "font": "Segoe UI",
                "color": "#000000"
              },
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Production PY",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": null,
                  "format": ","
                },
                "text": {"field": "label2"}
              }
            }
          ],
          "resolve": {
            "axis": {"y": "independent"},
            "scale": {"stroke": "independent", "fill": "independent"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent", "stroke": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you David. Seems I was close... Thanks for all your help :)